# OpenSSL takes subject name from server key and not config

Tags: openssl

Why my generated certificate Owner's CN is not "config.com" ?

My config file

```
[ ca ]
default_ca      = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
dir             = .
certificate     = rootCA.crt
private_key     = rootCA.key
certs           = $dir/certsdb          # Where the issued certs are kept
new_certs_dir   = $certs                # default place for new certs.
database        = $dir/db.txt           # required file
default_md      = sha256                # which md to use.
serial          = $dir/serial           # required file
default_days    = 365                   # how long to certify for
policy          = policy_custom
unique_subject  = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of several ctificates with same subject.

[ policy_custom ]
countryName             = supplied
stateOrProvinceName     = match
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = supplied
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ req ]
default_bits       = 2048
default_md         = sha512
default_keyfile    = rootCA.key
prompt             = yes
encrypt_key        = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName            = "US"           # C=
organizationName       = "ConfigOrg"   # O=
commonName             = "config.com"   # CN=
```

My `server-signed.pem`

```
$ keytool -printcert -file server-signed.pem
Owner: CN=CN1, O=Company1, ST=Some-State, C=US
...
```

```
$ openssl ca -create_serial -config ./example.cnf -infiles server.pem
Using configuration from ./example.cnf
Enter pass phrase for rootCA.key:
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows
countryName           :PRINTABLE:'US'
stateOrProvinceName   :ASN.1 12:'Some-State'
organizationName      :ASN.1 12:'Company1'
commonName            :ASN.1 12:'CN1'
Certificate is to be certified until Feb 25 08:10:15 2021 GMT (365 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:y


1 out of 1 certificate requests certified, commit? [y/n]y
Write out database with 1 new entries
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 3 (0x3)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=Some-State, O=RootCAOrg, Inc., OU=Root CA OU, CN=Root CA CN
```

```
$ keytool -printcert -file certsdb/01.pem
Owner: CN=CN1, O=Company1, ST=Some-State, C=US
Issuer: CN=Root CA CN, OU=Root CA OU, O="RootCAOrg, Inc.", ST=Some-State, C=US
```

Reference
https://docs.openkm.com/kcenter/view/okm-6.4/configuring-openssl.html#CreatetheOpenSSLConfigurationFile

Comment: The subject name in the cert comes from the CSR, and the `ca` interactive display clearly shows this.You don't show or even describe how you created the CSR.

Comment: You're right, how should I create CSR ?